# Matching a link's fragment with the url's fragment with jquery?

Tags: jquery, hash, parent-child, fragment, parents

How can I find the match in a link's fragment with the url's fragment and then highlight the link's parent?

HTML,

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="http://example.come/#/story/article-1/">Link 1</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="http://example.come/#/story/article-2/">Link 2</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="http://example.come/#/story/article-3/">Link 3</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <a href="http://example.come/#/story/article-4/">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

jquery,

```
//var fragment = location.hash;
fragment = '#/story/article-3/';

string = $('.item').find('a').attr('href');
array_string = string.split('#');

last_item = array_string[array_string.length - 1];
if(fragment == '#'+last_item) 
{
   alert('match!');

   // this is my theory... but I don't know how to get the object that matches the fragment.
   match_object.parents().css({background:'red'});
}
```

So, in this case, the **Link 3**'s container element should be highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elegant shortest solution

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QeJBr/2/)**

```
fragment = '#/story/article-3/';
$('.item a[href$="' + fragment + '"]').parent().css({background:'red'});
```

Another less elegant option but an example of why your code wasn't working as expected.

**[Live Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/QeJBr/)**

Without using `.each` you will only get the href for the first link, so it can never match the other. So basically I just took your logic wrapped it with each, and modified your selector a bit to turn the div background red. I recommend option one however.

```
//var fragment = location.hash;
fragment = '#/story/article-3/';

$('.item').find('a').each(
    function(){
        array_string = $(this).attr('href').split('#');

        last_item = array_string[array_string.length - 1];

        if(fragment == '#'+last_item) 
        {
           alert('match!');

           $(this).css({background:'red'});
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) out the links that don't match our fragment and apply css.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NakUu/)

```
var fragment = '#/story/article-3/';
$('div.item').find('a').filter(function(i) {
    return $(this).attr('href').indexOf(fragment) > -1
}).parent('div').css({background:'red'});
```

Comment: Good, but you should use `parent()` instead of `parents('div')` so that it only selects the parent of the anchor, instead of all divs in the anchor's DOM branch.

Comment: @Laurent OP used `parents()` in his code example. I'll change it anyway since it doesn't make much sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions.

First, you may not need all that looping.  Take a look at the [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).  That may be able to accomplish the search for you.

Once you have the match, then you should be able to do something like this:

```
$(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```